# Did app.set('port', port) is required for HTTP Server

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an application with Express application generator CLI using `npm install express-generator -g` with reference of [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

What is the use of express `app.set('port', port)`, While I am using the [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) Server ?

Application is working fine even I removed `app.set('port', port)`

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('usr-mgmt:server');
var http = require('http');
const { port } = require('../config');

app.set('port', port); // Working fine even after Removed this line 
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Whether I need to add `app.set('port', port)` on my test case ? Like the code generated by express generator ?

```
const app = require('../app.js');
let { port } = require('../config');

before(function () {
    server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);
});
```

Even test case is working fine without `app.set('port', port)`.

Why the [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) using this without use ?

Comment: Express allows you to set application variables using app.set - but this is just a fancy way for defining variables. You can later get the values for these variables using app.get

Comment: Sooner or later, you are going to need to tell your app to listen for traffic on a specific port. that's why express added it.